# Converting mavlink c library to dll

Tags: dll, mavlink

Is it possible to convert `MAVLink C library` to `.so` using eclipse?

I'm trying to call `mavlink` library from `lunix RT` on `myRio1900` board.

Answer (score 0):

MAVLink is a header-only library: a bunch of typedefs and macros scattered in header files. No need to compile and link, just include and use it.